# How can I release google app action in production?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I have integrated app actions in my app which is already published on google play console (not with app actions).

I am able to run it using [Action Assistant tool](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/test-tool) and voice command on my device, however I am not able to run it on other devices with release build.

Also, since my app is already published on google play, shall I get it reviewed with app actions integration ?

What is the process to release it in production? Any reference would be helpful.

Location: **India**.
Locale using: **en-US**

Thanks in advance.